# How to parse data recived from sql query into double

Tags: android, sqlite, parsing, android-sqlite

I created sql query for getting data from table Price in which I'm passing 4 arguments from table Logs. I want to retrieve 4 price values. 
 I create this in my Logs class and arguments that I'm passing are Logs getters.
I have probably messed up sql query. 
And after that I need to parse into double and multiply with method getResult(). 
My question is how properly create this sql query and parse it to double or int?
Here is my code. Please help.

```
public double getResult() {
        double log_length, log_diameter, length, diameter, result;
        log_length = Integer.parseInt(getLength().toString());
        log_diameter = Integer.parseInt(getDiameter().toString());
        length = log_length / 100;
        diameter = log_diameter * log_diameter * 3.14159265;
        result = length * diameter / 40000;
        return result;
    }

    public Cursor getPrice() {
        Cursor cursor = db.query("Price", new String[]{"price_stump_kn", "price_stump_eur", "road_price_kn", "road_price_eur"}, "sort = ? AND grade = ? AND length = ? BETWEEN diameter_dg = ? AND diameter_gg = ?",
                new String[]{getSort_id(), getGrade(), getLength(), getDiameter(), getDiameter()}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Price price = new Price();
                price.setStumpPrice_kn(cursor.getString(0));
                price.setStumpPrice_eur(cursor.getString(1));
                price.setRoadPrice_kn(cursor.getString(2));
                price.setRoadPrice_eur(cursor.getString(3));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static SQLiteDatabase simpledb=null;
    public static String dbname="demo";
    public static String tablename="price";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        simpledb=this.openOrCreateDatabase(dbname, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        try
        {

            simpledb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tablename + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,price1 double,price2 double,address varchar)");
            simpledb.execSQL("insert into '" + tablename + "'(price1,price2,address)values('2201.28','802.78','xyz');");
            simpledb.execSQL("insert into '" + tablename + "'(price1,price2,address)values('222656','707.77','xyz');");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    Fildata();
}

    public  void Fildata()
    {
        try
        {
            Cursor c=simpledb.rawQuery("select * from '"+tablename+"')",null);

            System.out.print("result"+c.toString());
            Log.d("SQL ", c.toString());
            if(c.getCount()>0)
            {
                while (c.moveToNext())
                {
                    double price1=c.getDouble(1);
                    double price2=c.getDouble(2);
                    add=c.getString(3);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," "+price1+"  "+price2,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Just edited question with new code. I change my method for price. But it is not good. I need to get all 4 prices and multiply each of that with getResult() method.

Comment: @RubyDigger19 Don't change the question; this would make the answer invalid. If this answer solved your original problem, accept it. If you have a different problem, ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, It has helped. I'll accept your answer. But can I ask you how to get parsed values from cursor and use them in other method?